# elasticsearch return unique matched values

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently started looking at elasticsearch, I'm in the process of learning what it can do and decide how I can use it in my projects.

For one project I used a couchdb (noSQL) database. The client can search it using couchdb views. Easy, but limited in functionality.
I'd like to have elasticsearch to open up the data in a far more rich way.

Searching for composers and titles of musical pieces is now handled by elasticsearch with amazingly fast 'query_string's. And it's fuzzy!

There is one thing however I did not manage to accomplish with elasticsearch, but I'm pretty sure it's possible, I'm just missing it.

It's about the autocomplete functionality when entering instrument names.
For example:
I have 2 documents (musical pieces) with different instruments needed to play them:

```
{
    title: 'Awesome Piece',
    authors: [{
        name: 'John Doe',
        role: 'composer'
    }, {
        name: 'Shakespeare',
        role: 'lyricist'
    }],
    instruments: [
        'soprano',
        'alto',
        'tenor',
        'bass',
        'trumpet',
        'trumpet',
        'piano'
    ]
}

{
    title: 'Not so Awesome Piece',
    authors: [{
        name: 'Another J. Doe',
        role: 'composer'
    }, {
        name: 'Little John',
        role: 'arranger'
    }],
    instruments: [
        'trombone',
        'organ'
    ]
}
```

To enter a new musical piece there is a field to insert instrument names. I'd like the offer an autocomplete.
So if the user types 't', I want a list of all instruments matching 't*': `['tenor', 'trumpet', 'trombone']`, if he types 'tr', I need: `['trumpet', 'trombone']`

The best I coold find was a query with an aggregation, but it searches for documents and aggregates them as a whole, returning all instruments of the document(s) found with the query.

And off course, I want the autocomplete to be fuzzy in the end.

Can anybody point me in a direction?
Thanks in advance!

(I'm running elasticsearch 2.3, but I don't mind upgrading!)

Comment: You should experiment with the [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) which provides exactly what you need and supports fuzziness.

Comment: That looks like what I need. I wonder how I missed it ...

Comment: The ES ecosystem has been growing pretty big so it's pretty easy to miss something ;-) Glad, you're on the right path.

Comment: @Val I can't get it to work. The completion suggester won't give me unique results. And since the default size is 5 (and it shouldn't be larger) it will give me 'trumpet' 5 times when searching for 't' (I have 500+ documents now). Since 'tenor' only shows once in the db it will only pop up if I increase the size to 150 (which is a bad idea).

Comment: @HansVereyken Did you ever find a solution for this?